# How to enable emulated cursor in KaiOS app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigator, kaios

I went through the official docs of KaiOS and did the following to enable emulated cursor on a particular page(component) in react.js. I ran the project in chrome, KaiOS simulator but not on a real device.

Added following in `manifest.webapp`

```
"type": "privileged", // or "certified"
  "permissions": {
    "spatialnavigation-app-manage": {}
  }
```

And tried doing this in particular page:

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.navigator.spatialNavigationEnabled = true;
      return () => {
        window.navigator.spatialNavigationEnabled = true;
      };
    }
  }, []);
```

But gives this error:
`Property 'spatialNavigationEnabled' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.`

What am I missing here? What should I do it to enable cursor effectively?

Answer (score 1):

I got the cursor enabled adding the property

```
"cursor": true,
```

In the root of the manifest.

Comment: did it work on while testing in browser or simulator? Or does it only work on real device?

Comment: I test it in a real device.

Answer (score 0):

```
"permissions": {
    "spatialnavigation-app-manage": {}
  }
```

In the code where you want to enable the cursor, add the following code in the function:

```
navigator.spatialNavigationEnabled = true;
```

Comment: Worth noting that this permission is only available on privileged and certified apps. It allows for toggling the cursor on and off at runtime. The manifest property enables the cursor categorically and works in web apps as well.